# Why does CakePHP load so slowly when I hit refresh?

Tags: cakephp

Whenever I am developing with CakePHP, it's SLOW when I am refreshing. However, it loads pretty decent when I open a new tab and just go to the same page. It loads SO slow that it reaches the timeout. It's just hanging all the time when I refresh the page.

I don't think it is my database, however, I am unsure. I'm usually just making CSS changes. How can I speed it up?

Comment: I wonder if this could be a problem with the cache.

Comment: It could be, but I am not sure.

Comment: The refresh button forces the browser to reload lots of things it normally retrieves from cache like images, css and js. Especially if a page includes many of those files it can take a lot of time. Chrome and safari can both give you a timeline of the network activity while loading a page which can help you find where all the time is spend. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: Try one experiment: set debug mode to 0 then refresh your webpage and and set it to 2 again in your app/Config/core.php file. It somehow worked for me. I also cleaned the browser cache and app/tmp/cache. I know this is not a stable solution. But it worked.